# How to list all bad data from dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark, udf

My dataframe is like below:

[image]

It turns out there are some rows with field timestamp is most likely empty so I need to exclude them.

```
split_log_cleaned_df = split_log_df.filter(col('timestamp') != '')
```

Excluding them seems easy and working, I want to list them but not successful

```
split_log_bad_df = split_log_df.filter(col('timestamp') == '')
```

The full script is below:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions  import date_format
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType
def dayOfWeek(s):
    return date_format(s, 'E')

func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%b/%Y'), DateType())  

from pyspark.sql.functions import split, regexp_extract 
split_log_df = log_df.select(regexp_extract('value', r'^([^\s]+\s)', 1).alias('host'),
                          regexp_extract('value', r'^.*\[(\d\d/\w{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} -\d{4})]', 1).alias('ori_timestamp'),
                          regexp_extract('value', r'((\d\d/\w{3}/\d{4}))', 1).alias('timestamp'),   
                          regexp_extract('value', r'^.*"\w+\s+([^\s]+)\s+HTTP.*"', 1).alias('path'),
                          regexp_extract('value', r'^.*"\s+([^\s]+)', 1).cast('integer').alias('status'),
                          regexp_extract('value', r'^.*\s+(\d+)$', 1).cast('integer').alias('content_size'),
                          func(regexp_extract('value', r'((\d\d/\w{3}/\d{4}))', 1)).alias('real_timestamp'),
                          dayOfWeek(func(regexp_extract('value', r'((\d\d/\w{3}/\d{4}))', 1))).alias('weekday'))
split_log_df.show(10, truncate=False)

#split_log_df = split_log_df.filter(split_log_df['timestamp']<>'').count()
#split_log_df =split_log_df.groupBy('weekday').count().sort('weekday')
#split_log_df.show(10, truncate=False)

split_log_cleaned_df = split_log_df.filter(col('timestamp') != '')
#split_log_cleaned_df = split_log_df.filter(col('timestamp').isNull)
split_log_cleaned_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Here is the error message:

> ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d/%b/%Y'

How can I list all the problematic rows?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think your error is saying you have an empty string

Comment: I also believe there are some rows with empty string, I also was able to exclude them but the current problem is how do I find and list them to a new dataframe that I can do more investigation. Thanks.

Comment: Can you not use `filter` or some "where not empty condition" before you apply the udf? Or use a `try` statement in the Python code?

Comment: Thanks, can we go realtime chat?

Comment: Just use `func` on the `split_log_df` **after** you do the `regexp_extract` in the `select` function there. I think you are close, just your data isn't "perfect", or your regex extraction isn't always returning you the correct data.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120894/pyspark